# jquery .prop('disabled', true) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to toggle `disabled = true|false` on a `<input type="text">`, using a checkbox. I am able to get the value of the input, but I cannot set the input to disabled.

my jquery/js code

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker();
    $('body').on('change', '.housing', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'dorms') {
            $(this).parent().next(".dorms").show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().siblings(".dorms").hide();
        }
    });
    $('body').on('change', '.single', function () {
        if ($(this).checked) {
            $('#echo1').text($(this).prev(".roommate").val());  // this works
            $(this).prev(".roommate").val(''); // does not empty the input
            $(this).prev(".roommate").disabled = true; // does not set to disabled
            $(this).prev(".roommate").prop('disabled', true);  // does not set to disabled
            $('#echo2').text($(this).prev(".roommate").prop('disabled')); // always says false
        } else {
            $('#echo1').text($(this).prev(".roommate").val()); // this works
            $(this).prev(".roommate").disabled = false;  // always stays false
            $('#echo2').text($(this).prev(".roommate").prop('disabled'));  // always says false
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

my html code

```
<div class="registration_housing particpant_0" data-sync="0">
    <div>
        <label class="particpant_0"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Off Campus (not included)</label>
        <input type="radio" name="housing[0]" value="none" class="housing" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>On Campus</label>
        <input type="radio" name="housing[0]" value="dorms" class="housing" />
    </div>
    <div class="dorms" style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <label>Checkin:</label>
            <input type="text" name="check_in[0]" class="date" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Checkout:</label>
            <input type="text" name="check_out[0]" class="date" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Roommate:</label>
            <input type="text" name="roommate[0]" class="roommate" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="roommate_single[0]" value="single" class="single" />check for singe-occupancy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <hr size="1" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label id="echo1"></label>
</div>
<div>
    <label id="echo2"></label>
</div>
```

you can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/78dQE/1/

Any idea why I can get the value of `(".roommate")` - ie. `$(this).prev(".roommate").val()`
but
`$(this).prev(".roommate").disabled = true;`
OR
`$(this).prev(".roommate").prop('disabled', true);`
will not set `(".roommate")` to disabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is mixing jquery with DOM element attributes

change  `if ($(this).checked) {` to  `if (this.checked) {`

With jquery you would do

```
$(this).is(':checked') // But you could just do this.checked
```

And

```
 $(this).prev(".roommate").prop('disabled', false); // or $(this).prev(".roommate")[0].disabled = false;
```

instead of

```
   $(this).prev(".roommate").disabled = false;
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZWXq/)

So you just probably need this:

```
 $('body').on('change', '.single', function () {
    $(this).prev(".roommate").prop('disabled', this.checked).val('');
 });
```

Comment: To elaborate, a jQuery object is really an array-like collection over one or more DOM elements. So if you know your jQuery object only contains one element, as in this case, then you could do `$(this).prev(".roommate")[0].disabled = false`, which is what jQuery does under the hood (for each DOM element in the jQuery object, in this case just the one) when you call `prop('disabled', false)`. This is just for education purposes; use the `prop()` function since it's more readable.

Comment: "Note: Do not use [removeProp] to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead."

Comment: @austin Yes valid point, i remember answering with the same point to some other question early during my jquery answering days :). Infact if i remember correctly that warning is given in the jquery doc for removeProp itself.